# Miter saw tripping GFCI outlets

Tags: electrical, gfci, powertools

Recently I installed some 15A GFCI outlets in my basement to make using power tools more convenient, but quickly had problems with them tripping on my miter saw. This seemed extra odd since my miter saw doesn't even have a ground wire.

I found lots of help online about how to test these and table saws with ohm meters to look for shorts, but none of those explained my problem, especially once I realized I had been using it for years on an outlet that was also GFCI protected. I figured I should post my solution now that I figured it out.

Comment: Is it a variable speed saw?

Comment: Is it connected to an extension cable? If not, what's the condition of the plug cable? If it is, what's the gauge and length of the cable?

Comment: My saw is single speed. It worked correctly with and without a heavy extension cord in good condition on different 20A GFCI outlets. It failed with and without the same extension cord on different 15A GFCI outlets.

I think my neighbor's saw is also single speed. He used a beat up extension cord that may not even have a ground pin in both the successful 20A test and unsuccessful 15A test.

Comment: What is the power rating of the miter saw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested my miter saw on a 20A GFCI outlet, it worked fine. I tested my neighbors miter saw on a second 20A GFCI outlet on a second circuit in my house, it also worked fine. But after plugging my miter saw into the 2 indoor 15A GFCI outlets, it would trip the GFCI the moment I started the saw. My neighbor reported a similar problem when he plugged his miter saw into my outdoor 15A GFCI outlet.

So, while it could have been a short, and tripping a GFCI is often evidence that there is something (dangerously) wrong with your power tool, for me the solution was to replace the 15A GFCI outlets with 20A GFCI outlets (on a 20A circuit). Both saws are working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

I am a retired electrical engineer and amateur handyman. I have experienced the same problems with GFCIs even at 20 amp rating. Particularly skil-saws and table saws.  I have also disassembled GFCI units and my first observation is it's 100 lb of s*** in a 50 lb bag. Therefore all components are as small as possible.

**My conjecture** is that power tools at startup draw peak currents well in excess of 15 or even 20 amps for a brief moment - a few milliseconds. While that doesn't trip a breaker, it can easily exceed the saturation of the tiny ferrite core of the differential transformer at the heart of a GFCI. It is the differential current sensor between the hot and neutral legs that both pass through the core of that transformer. Once the core is saturated, any expectation of proper operation goes out the window. I have given up using any gfis in my garage workshop. -Stuby

Answer (score 0):

Most miter and table saws are high amperage draws, some even exceeding 15amps. Sounds like you are overdrawing the circuit. That's why they work in your neighbors 20a receptacles. I would replace the receptacles with 20amp receptacles and make sure you have 12-2 wiring.

Comment: That wouldn't trip a GFCI receptacle though -- GFCI receptacles are differential trip only, not the combined OC/SC/Diff (ground fault) protection provided by a GFCI breaker

Comment: That's what everything I read online said, too. But replacing the receptacles cured the problem.